# PlayWright: Page.title() returning empty value. Trying to add automation in electron-vue project

Tags: playwright, playwright-test, electron-vue

For automated testing, I'm attempting to incorporate Playwright into my electron-vue project. I run the test, and Page.title() returns "". Here is the code:

```
test("renders the screen splash", async () => {
  let page: Page;
  page = await electronApp.firstWindow();
  console.log("Title: ", await page.title());
  const title = await page.title()
  expect(title).toBe('Splash')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try if it helps?

```
    test("renders the screen splash", async () => {
      let page: Page;
      page = await electronApp.firstWindow();
      // add the following line
      await page.waitForLoadState();
      console.log("Title: ", await page.title());
      const title = await page.title()
      expect(title).toBe('Splash')
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you also look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74733550/playwright-electron-is-it-possible-to-get-browserwindow-from-page