# Playwright/JaveScript Can only access page.title() when debugging, otherwise get empty string

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, playwright

I'm writing some automation which tests that a new window is popped up when a link is clicked.  I'm validating this new window by checking the title of the new window. When debugging, I can see that the title gets set as expected, however when I run the test, in my expect statement it says it's received "" (empty string).  This same snippet of code works in other similar tests also, I'm a little stuck as to why this is happening, and any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated!

I found a similar issue here, but have already tried the suggested solution without any luck.  [PlayWright: Page.title() returning empty value. Trying to add automation in electron-vue project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715616/playwright-page-title-returning-empty-value-trying-to-add-automation-in-elec)

Here is some code:

```
// testing.spec.ts

const newWindow = await Utils.getNewWindow(page, openWindowLink);
const title = await newWindow.title();  // When debugging, I can see the title, when running get empty string
if (title = 'Privacy error') {
    // Sometimes we have to bypass privacy error.  This if statement hits successfully when debugging, but I assume not when running as title is an empty string
}
await newWindow.waitForTimeout(5000);
const newTitle = await newWindow.title();
expect(await newTitle).toEqual('New Window Title');  // Again returning empty string when running, but is there when debugging


// Utils.ts

static async getNewWindow(page: Page, linkLocator: Locator) : Promise<Page> {
    await linkLocator.click();
    const newPage = await pagePromise;
    await newPage.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded');
    return newPage;
}
```

I've tried multiple solutions:

1. Added waits to allow page to load

   a) getNewWindow already has a waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded')

   b) Added a waitForTimeout(5000) just to be sure (I've even tried 50000 just for kicks)
2. Creating new title variable at the moment we're expecting the title value
3. Running with "Show browser" checked

   a) This introduced a whole new problem, but appeared to find the title at least.  Ideally we'd run without show browser and I can figure out that other problem another time as our regression doesn't run with browser showing.

   b) It's worth noting that everything else looks good when using "Show browser".  I can see the new window pop up.  If even follows the bypass flow, so it definitely finds the title.  We just then encounter a new problem, and ideally want it to run without "show browser" anyway

Thanks again in advance for any help

Comment: `getNewWindow` looks wrong. Locators already wait, so whatever `pagePromise` is probably doesn't make sense to wait on. This looks like a race condition where the `click` that triggers a nav resolves before `newPage.waitForLoadState('domcontentloaded')`, which is enough to get a title. Can you share a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I found an alternate solution I will post (I'm honestly not too sure of the difference) that I will post here.  A minimal reproducible example may be difficult to mimic exactly what my repro is doing as it requires a backend API to handle the navigation of the button click.  I will post my work around which can hopefully help someone else, but if I come up with a better minimal reproducible example to get an even better answer for others, I will follow up here.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of waitForLoadState, use `waiForURL`.

```
await page.click('locatorInfo'); // any object which need to be clicked
await page.waitForURL(/.*checkout/);
```

> Note: In modern web applications(like angular/react) 'domcontentloaded' is
> not the true indicator of page load state.

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will experiment with this and mark as answer if it fixes the problem (I've already began, but having issues matching the regex on the URL.  It's massive with a ton of query strings).  Also, is there a similar way to handle this in the case the the URL changes?   Or do we need to match exactly what we're expected.

It's worth noting also that in my scenario we're actually clicking a button, which calls an API that returns a URL to redirect to.  I'm not sure if this would be any different than click an "a href" link as you mentioned?

Thanks again

Comment: The object does not matter , it may be button or link whatever needs to be clicked. Also as it supports regex, you may enter flexibly  the static part only and it will work in all scenarios like in above case "checkout" can be anywhere in the desired url, which is pretty flexible.

Comment: Awesome thanks again for your reply!  At a most basic level, I set waitForURL(/.*/), and this got rid of the error and works now while debugging.  It also fixed the other error I was getting when running with 'Show browser' selected.  That error was "gation failed because page was closed" even though the page never actually closed.  I will experiment with the URL regex, but since we care only for the title as confirmation, this is good for now.  Thanks again for your help!